# Numpy remove unique rows based on column

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to get an array where it would remove all unique rows based on the first column. My array works looks like this,

```
[['Aaple' 'Red']
 ['Aaple' '0.0']
 ['Banana' 'Yellow']
 ['Banana' '0.0']
 ['Orange' 'Orange']
 ['Pear' 'Yellow']
 ['Pear' '0.0']
 ['Strawberry' 'Red']]
```

I want it to look like this,

```
[['Aaple' 'Red']
 ['Aaple' '0.0']
 ['Banana' 'Yellow']
 ['Banana' '0.0']
 ['Pear' 'Yellow']
 ['Pear' '0.0']]
```

Where it would remove the unique values from column one. My current code looks like this,

```
arr = np.array(["Aaple", "Pear", "Banana"])

arr2 = np.array([["Strawberry", "Red"], ["Aaple", "Red"], ["Orange", "Orange"], ["Pear", "Yellow"], ["Banana", "Yellow"]])


arr = arr.reshape(-1,1)
zero_arr = np.zeros((len(arr), 1))
arr = np.column_stack((arr, zero_arr))
combine = np.vstack((arr2, arr))
sort = combine[combine[:,0].argsort()]
#Where the first array printed is sort
```

I was able to get `['Aaple' 'Banana' 'Pear']`, the rows I want to keep by adding `x = sort[:-1][sort[1:] == sort[:-1]]`, what would be the next steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be easier to use [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(sort, columns=list('ab'))
df[df.groupby('a').a.transform('count')>1].values
```

Result:

```
array([['Aaple', 'Red'],
       ['Aaple', '0.0'],
       ['Banana', 'Yellow'],
       ['Banana', '0.0'],
       ['Pear', 'Yellow'],
       ['Pear', '0.0']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: I am trying to do this all in Numpy, I have a large dataset and using pandas takes too long, is it not possible using Numpy? @stef

Comment: @AndrewHorowitz it's probably possible doing it in pure numpy as pandas uses numpy under the hood, but I don't think that it'll so much faster than pandas as the involved operations here are being carried out on numpy arrays (maybe I'm wrong)